# How do I show percentages in a formattable with color_tiles in an R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

**Situation:**

I am plotting data from a given dataset. I color each cell in a row according to its ratio of the sum of the row. This works fine. The code is posted below.

**Problem:**

I want to express the values of the cells as percentages. For example, instead of `0.547` I want `54.7 %`.

**Question:**

How do I need to modify the code in order to show percentages?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(formattable)


  shinyApp(


    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
        )
      )
    ),


    server = function(input, output) {



        myIris=iris[c(1,89,124),c("Species","Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
        myIris$sumOfRow=myIris$Sepal.Length+myIris$Sepal.Width+myIris$Petal.Length+myIris$Petal.Width
        myIris$Sepal.Length=myIris$Sepal.Length/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Sepal.Width=myIris$Sepal.Width/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Petal.Length=myIris$Petal.Length/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Petal.Length=myIris$Petal.Length/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Petal.Width=myIris$Petal.Width/myIris$sumOfRow

    myFormattable <- formattable(myIris, lapply(1:nrow(myIris), function(row, col=1:5) {
    area(row, col=1:5) ~ color_tile("transparent", "red")
    }))
    myDatatable=as.datatable(myFormattable)



   output$mytable=DT::renderDataTable({
        myDatatable
  })


    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatPercentage()`. You just need to multiply your column by 100 before.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(formattable)

 shinyApp(


    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
        )
      )
    ),


    server = function(input, output) {



        myIris=iris[c(1,89,124),c("Species","Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]
        myIris$sumOfRow=myIris$Sepal.Length+myIris$Sepal.Width+myIris$Petal.Length+myIris$Petal.Width
        myIris$Sepal.Length=myIris$Sepal.Length/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Sepal.Width=myIris$Sepal.Width/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Petal.Length=myIris$Petal.Length/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Petal.Length=myIris$Petal.Length/myIris$sumOfRow
        myIris$Petal.Width=myIris$Petal.Width/myIris$sumOfRow

    myFormattable <- formattable(myIris, lapply(1:nrow(myIris), function(row, col=1:5) {
    area(row, col=1:5) ~ color_tile("transparent", "red")
    }))
    #myDatatable=as.datatable(myFormattable)



   output$mytable=DT::renderDataTable({
myFormattable$Sepal.Width_p <- myFormattable$Sepal.Width*100
        datatable(myFormattable) %>% formatPercentage("Sepal.Width_p")
  })


    }
  )
```

EDIT:

You could simply use the function `percent`.

```
myIris$Sepal.Width_p <- percent(myIris$Sepal.Width)

        myFormattable <- formattable(myIris, lapply(1:nrow(myIris), function(row, col=1:5) {
        area(row, col=1:5) ~ color_tile("transparent", "red")
        }))
```

and then:

```
myDatatable=as.datatable(myFormattable)
myDatatable
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I need to keep the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
  datatable(myFormattable) %>% formatPercentage('Sepal.Length', 2)
})
```

However, this will change your color bar style. I'm not familiar with the formattable package, but you can refer to [How to Style DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html) to apply your styles using DT's methods.

Comment: Thanks. I need to keep the colours, though. That's why I chose formattable in the first place. Also thanks for the link. However, I had tried this, before I changed to formattable.